# Pinning or starring a post on timeline through the Facebook PHP API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way to programmatically pin or star a post that an API app is publishing to a user's or page's timeline through the graph api?

Asking for permissions is not a problem; I am under the assumption that users of this app will grant publish_actions or full publish_stream permissions.

Answer (score 0):

See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550302/1784062

**Pinning** via Graph API seems not possible at the moment afaik.

For **starring** use:

```
POST /<post_id>/ with param timeline_visibility = starred
```

`timeline_visibility` must be one of the following values: `hidden`, `normal`, `starred`.