# How to star a post on a facebook fanpage using graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm posting on my fanpage but i want to do highlight posts. Any suggestions?

I have to star them one by one on the fanpage. Is there any way to do this? I also read the documentation but there is no examples.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts

Sample of code:

```
  $args = array(
      'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
      'message'       => 'MY MESSAGE'
  );

  $post_id = $facebook->api("/MY PAGE ID/feed","post",$args);
```

Im using PHP SDK 3.1.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
POST /<post_id>/ with param timeline_visibility = starred
```

`timeline_visibility` must be one of the following values: `hidden`, `normal`, `starred`.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19861323/1784062.