# Pinning facebook page post to the top of the wall

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

On facebook pages an admin can pin a post to the top of the wall. I want to do that through the `facebook php sdk`. I've already read https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550302/1784062 so I tried the following code but it isn't pinning the post to the top of the wall.

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        "POST",
        "/".$pageId."/feed",
        array(
                "access_token"      => $page_token,
                "message"           => $message,
                "time_visibility"   => "starred"
        )
))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

**EDIT:** Also `"timeline_visibility" => "starred"` don't work.